# How i can fix preg_match() expects parameter error?

Tags: php, laravel

When i try login to site from Steam, i received error:

> ErrorException in SteamController.php line 50:
>       preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

For test i try to delete code from line 50, but nothing happened.

My login function in SteamController.php

```
    public function login()
    {


        if ($this->steamAuth->validate()) {
            $steamID = $this->steamAuth->getSteamId();
            $user = User::where('steamid64', $steamID)->first();
            if (!is_null($user)) {

                $steamInfo = $this->steamAuth->getUserInfo();
                $nick = $steamInfo->getNick();
                if (preg_match("/Admin|admins|admin|/i", $nick)) {

                    $nick = 'ADmin';
                }
                \DB::table('users')->where('steamid64', $steamID)->update(['username' => $nick, 'avatar' => $steamInfo->getProfilePictureFull()]);

                if ($user->partner == 0) {

                    \DB::table('users')->where('steamid64', $steamID)->update(['partner' => \Request::cookie('ref')]);
                }

            } else {

                $steamInfo = $this->steamAuth->getUserInfo();
                $nick = $steamInfo->getNick();
                if (preg_match("/|Admin|admins|admin/i", $nick)) {

                    $nick = 'Admin';
                }
                $user = User::create([
                    'username' => $nick,
                    'avatar' => $steamInfo->getProfilePictureFull(),
                    'steamid' => $steamInfo->getSteamID(),
                    'steamid64' => $steamInfo->getSteamID64(),
                    'partner' => \Request::cookie('ref')
                ]);

            }
            Auth::login($user, true);
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return $this->steamAuth->redirect();
        }
    }
```

What i need to do, for fix error?

Comment: What is the value of `$nick`?

Comment: What is the output of $steamInfo->getNick()?

Comment: $nick get Steam nickname

Comment: its an object obviously. as per Error variable you passing is an object. its necessary to pass String.

Comment: Please can you show the  output of `dd($nick);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to lack of information, I'm assuming that you're using `invisnik/laravel-steam-auth` package to handle Steam social login.

Being that case, `$steamInfo` is a instance of `Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamInfo` which extends `Illuminate\Support\Fluent`.

So, I'm guessing `$steamInfo->getNick()` is an attempt to retrieve the private `$this->attributes['nick']` property, if that's the case, then you're doing it the wrong way.

```php
$steamInfo->getNick() // returns itself, an object. (Thats probably why you're getting "expects parameter 2 to be string, object given").

// The correct way:
$steamInfo->nick;
// or
$steamInfo->get('nick');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: one error is fix, but now `Missing argument 1 for Invisnik\LaravelSteamAuth\SteamInfo::getSteamID(), called inapp/Http/Controllers/SteamController.php on line 57 and defined` 57 line it: `'steamid' => $steamInfo->getSteamID(),`

Comment: It means the function $steamInfo->getSteamID() requires an argument, I don't know what that argument is but I think that's not the workaround. I guess its the same "Fluent" problem as before, take a look at lines 15 and 16 from [here](https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth/blob/v3.0.0/src/SteamInfo.php)... the package provides you with 2 attributes `steamID` and `steamID64` ready to be used: `$steamInfo->steamID` and `$steamInfo->steamID64`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Artem , please upvote and if the answer worked, please, accept it. Thank you